# "TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object"

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

I am making a text editing program with tkinter. I created a save button that uses pickle to dump the text into a .dat file but when I click said save button, I get the error that is in the title.

When I looked this problem up before, people said they were using some kind of multi-processing but I am not. How do I fix this? Should I use a different module other than pickle? (if so please tell me what to use)

(first time using this website so sorry if I'm doing this wrong)
The program code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pickle

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('800x500')
window.resizable(True,True)
window.title('Text Editor')

#**save problem**
def save():
        pickle.dump(text, open('textsave.dat', 'wb'))
        messagebox.INFO(title='TextEditor',text='Saved Successfully')

def fontsize():
        text.config(font=fontsize_entry.get())

def textcolor():
        text.config(fg=color_entry.get())

#pickle.load(open('textsave.dat', 'rb'))

frame1 = ttk.Frame(master=window)
frame1.pack()

frame_label = ttk.Frame(master=frame1)
frame_label.pack()

frame_save = ttk.Frame(master=window)
frame_save.pack(pady=5)

frame2 = ttk.Frame(master=window)
frame2.pack(pady=15)

#the text box
text = tk.Text(window, font='"Annie Use Your Telescope" 20', fg='black')
text.pack()

#font related things
fontsize_entry = ttk.Entry(master=frame1,text='Font')
fontsize_entry.pack(side='left')
fontsize_label = ttk.Label(master=frame_label,text='"font" fontsize bold/italic',font='Arial 12')
fontsize_label.pack(side='left', padx=30)
fontsize_button = ttk.Button(master=frame1,text='Enter', command=fontsize)
fontsize_button.pack(side='left')

#color related things
color_entry = ttk.Entry(master=frame1,text='Color')
color_entry.pack(side='right')
color_label = ttk.Label(master=frame_label,text='Text Color',font='Arial 12')
color_label.pack(side='right', padx=30)
color_button = ttk.Button(master=frame1,text='Enter', command=textcolor)
color_button.pack(side='right')

#save related things
save_button = ttk.Button(master=frame_save, text='Save', command=save)
save_button.pack(side='right',padx=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Tried saving text to .dat file using pickle, error appeared

Comment: The problem is that `text` is not just plain text; it is a `tk.Text` object.  You need to extract just the plain text, and then save that.  I beleive `text.get()` will give you just the actual text contents.

Answer (score 1):

`text` is a widget, not the text in the widget. You can't pickle tkinter objects.

If you just want to save the text, use the `get` method to get the data, and then just open and write to a file.

```
with open("textsave.dat", "w") as f:
    data = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    f.write(data)
```